# SAS, count variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Given the following macro variable:

```
 %let var = name salary work;
```

I need to create a macro variable which has the number of the variables in the var. In this example, this newly created macro variable is equal to 3.

Answer (score 4):

The basic concept here is using the `COUNTW` function.  You can't use that directly in a macro variable assignment though (in a `%let`), but you can use `%SYSFUNC` to enable you to use it.

```
%let var_count = %sysfunc(countw(&var.));
```

Note there are no quotation marks or similar.